# Cases where different types of Reports used?

Tags: report, odoo

**OpenERP 7 Reports** are mainly done by following methods:

- `PostgreSQL`
- `RML`
- `XSL/ XML`

I need to know at what scenario these different types of OpenERP Reports are used.

Can you provide scenarios with example for my better understanding.

```
Thanks & Regards,
Atchuthan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSL/XML was also an old reporting tool, which was used in OpenERP v5 and v6. It was used to produce XSLT reports, specially for complex reporting structure. But it's almost deprecated now.

Comment: Can u provide detail regarding Aeroo report??

Comment: Aeroo reporting is a new reporting engine for openerp, one can design report using open office and get output in .sxw, .doc format. It works based on open office / libre office library.

Comment: Is Aero Report a software used to design or is it a technique to design in Open office??

Answer (score 0):

Postgres reports - you lose all the benefits of the ORM - no functional fields, no related fields etc.  I presume you might do this for very raw data or outright performance but can't think of another reason unless you already have a lot of experience with 3rd party reporting tools sych as crystal.

RML - old method.

XSL/XML - not sure what you mean here.

Have a look at Webkit_report module  You get a powerful templating language (mako) and the benefits of the ORM.

There is also Aeroo but we have moved off that due mostly to memory leaks in headless open office as well as Pentaho connectors.

Comment: **For XSL/XML**
`Settings --> Actions --> Reports --> Search for Labels`

You can see OpenERP have used xsl/xml

What does this imply??

Comment: Can u provide detail regarding Aeroo report??